# Documents added to firebase instance in flutter app but not uploaded or visible in the firestore console website

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have trouble as I am trying to test the connection of my flutter app with firebase and get the bases of writing and reading documents in collections.
Here is my code for the main function where I am running my tests as I am not familiar with flutter and firebase yet:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  //test firestore
print(Firebase.app().name);
print(Firebase.app().options);
 

  var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  print(db);
// Create a new user with a first and last name
  final user = <String, dynamic>{
  "first": "Ada",
  "last": "Lovelace",
  "born": 1815
};

CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

//print documents in users collection

void printUserDocuments() {
  users.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      print('User document ID: ${doc.id}');
      print('Data: ${doc.data()}');
    });
  }).catchError((error) {
    print('Error getting documents: $error');
  });
}

printUserDocuments();

// Add a new document with a generated ID
users.add(user).then((DocumentReference doc) {
 print('DocumentSnapshot added with ID: ${doc.id}');
}).catchError((error) {
print('Error adding user: $error');
});

  runApp(const MyApp());

}
```

When I run the code, the part that is supposed to read my collection and print it to the console works and I realised that I get a new dummy user for each time I run the program. However nothing is visible in the firebase firestore console and no document is added to the users collection. I believe I am only modifying the instance of the database ´db’ locally but not uploading it to firebase but I don’t know how to fix this.

I tried to use await in front of the line that add the documents to make sure that the code doesn’t go on and skip the adding of the file but it resulted in the app not starting with a caught on exception.

I also tried different ways of adding the file that I found on different websites but I stuck with the one I found on the official « connect flutter to firebase » website.

Also I checked firebase login and flutterfife configure and all those commands ran successfully.

Comment: Instead of telling is what worked and what didn't in words, please edit your question (there's an `edit` link right under it) to show the log output you get - and indicate where that output isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: just check your firestore Rules 1st. and let us know with the proper info as @FrankvanPuffelen said

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, sorry for the silly question it should be very ismple but I am new to firebase, I indeed just had to change the rules section in firebase. It worked. Thank you !